# How to sort rows from smallest to largest using matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting

Sorry for so many question i post.

this is my another problem, how to sort rows from smallest to largest, (see picture below):

so here's my data and code:

```
A=
[a  b   c
1   2   3
4   5   1
0   1   0
2   1   2]
```

i used sort function:

```
B = [sort(A(1:end,:), 'ascend')]
```

but it didn't display the output i want.

[image]

smallest no. display in 1st column and large no. display in last column, so guys please help.

Comment: Did you try googling at least? What did you try?

Comment: have you looked at the [`sort`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) function ?

Comment: please check my problem again i already edit it. yes i used the sort.

Comment: From the documentation: "`B = sort(A,dim)` sorts the elements of A along dimension dim. For example, if A is a matrix, then `sort(A,2)` **sorts the elements in each row.**"

Comment: @nobel If you don't read the documentations properly, you would often end up asking/posting questions and this isn't the best place to learn basic things like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Sortrows: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html
2. Sort with argument 2, e.g. sort(A, 2):
   http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html?refresh=true

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this

```
a =

     1     2     3     4     5
     3     6     2     4     7
     9     6     5     8     4

 B1 = sort(a,2,'ascend')


B1 =

     1     2     3     4     5
     2     3     4     6     7
     4     5     6     8     9
```

More about this at [MathWorks](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html)